# How do I avoid loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I understand that in `R` it is best to avoid loops where possible. In that regard, I would like to perform the function of the code below but without using the nested loops.

The loops check whether the `f`'th element of the vector `things_I_want_to_find` is present in the `i`'th row of `thing_to_be_searched`. For example, when both `i` and `f` are 1, the code checks whether `"vocals"` is present in `john`'s row. Because `"vocals"` *is* present in `john`'s row, the name and instrument are added to vectors `instrument` and `name`. When both loops are complete these two vectors can be combined in a `data.frame`.

I know that there is the `apply()` family of functions in R but I don't know if they are able to be used in this case. Has anyone got any helpful hints or suggestions?

```
instrument<-c()

name<-c()

things_I_want_to_find<-c("vocals","drums","rhythm guitar","bass")

thing_to_be_searched<-
data.frame(
id=c("john","paul","george","ringo"),
a=c("vocals","bass","rhythm guitar","oboe"),
b=c("vocals","basoon","piano","clarinet"),
c=c("violin","vocals","french horn","drums"))
for(f in 1:length(things_I_want_to_find))
{
  for(i in 1:nrow(thing_to_be_searched))
  {
    n<-which(thing_to_be_searched[i,]==things_I_want_to_find[f])
    if(length(n)>0)
    {
      instrument<-c(instrument,as.character(thing_to_be_searched[i,][n][,1][1]))
      name<-c(name,as.character(thing_to_be_searched$id[i]))
    }

    
  }
}

desired_output<-data.frame(name=name,instrument=instrument)
desired_output
    name    instrument
1   john        vocals
2   paul        vocals
3  ringo         drums
4 george rhythm guitar
5   paul          bass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
thing_to_be_searched %>%
  # Melt wide data to long
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  # Drop unwanted column
  select(-name) %>%
  # Filter wanted values only
  filter( value %in% things_I_want_to_find) %>%
  # Only keep unique rows
  unique()
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id     value        
  <chr>  <chr>        
1 john   vocals       
2 paul   bass         
3 paul   vocals       
4 george rhythm guitar
5 ringo  drums
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

thing_to_be_searched %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(instrument = things_I_want_to_find[things_I_want_to_find %in% cur_data()]) %>%
  ungroup

#   id     instrument   
#  <chr>  <chr>        
#1 george rhythm guitar
#2 john   vocals       
#3 paul   vocals       
#4 paul   bass         
#5 ringo  drums
```

Comment: Today I learned: [cur_data](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R` with `reshape` (with `R 4.1.0`)

```
thing_to_be_searched |>
   setNames(c('id', paste0('a', 1:3))) |>
   reshape(direction = 'long',  varying  = 2:4, sep="") |>
   subset(a %in% things_I_want_to_find, select = c(id, a)) |>
   unique() |>
   `row.names<-`(NULL)
#      id             a
#1   john        vocals
#2   paul          bass
#3 george rhythm guitar
#4   paul        vocals
#5  ringo         drums
```

Comment: Nice use of pipes in base R!

Comment: Amazing new features of base R. Just got to know that R 4.1.0 is released (notified by your answer) :P